Desactivar control de versiones
soy un estudiante de desarrollo de software, accidentalmente cuando estaba aprendiendo el uso de git hice Git init en mi dirección C:/user/"mi usuario", eso hizo que constantemente este controlando esa dirección, quisiera saber si hay un método para desactivar ese control en esa dirección, dado que si uso git con un proyecto personal, de antemano agradezco la ayuda.

Git no está constantemente siguiendo los cambios que ocurren. Solo actúa cuando usas algún comando de git, o cuando estás usando algún IDE con git integrado.
Cuando clonas o inicializas un repositorio, Git crea una carpeta llamada .git dentro el mismo y suele estar oculta. Todo lo que tienes que hacer es borrarla. Puedes hacerlo ejecutando el siguiente comando en el símbolo del sistema:
rd C:\Users\%username%\.git /s /q

